# Create a new column in my table that has edited values from a pre-existing column which have been effected by a multiplier from a text input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

I am creating a Laravel site in which I have a table which displays pricing information from a database. Within this I have a Retail Price column which I want to use to then populate a discount price column by multiplying by a decimal. This decimal is generated by a text input. When I put in a multiplier and hit go nothing happens. No errors but it doesn't fill the column as I am hoping. Was wondering if anyone could help me in my troubles.

EDITED TO INCLUDE CHANGES FROM MEHMOOD!

This is my input for the multiplier:

```
<div>
    <button class="discbtn">Go!</button>
</div>

<div class="discinput">
    <label>Discount Multiplier:</label>
    <input id="disc" type="text" name="dc" style="text-align: right" placeholder="Discount e.g. .2 for 20%" />

</div>
```

This is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".discbtn").click(function () {
        var discValue = $("#disc").val();
        $('#stand td:eq(4)').each(function () {
            if (isNaN($('#stand td:eq(4)').text())) {
                $('#stand td:eq(5)').each(function () {
                    $('#stand td:eq(5)').text($('#stand td:eq(4)').text() * discValue);
                })
            }
        })
    })
})
```

HTML for the table:

```
<div id="pricetable">
   <table id="stand">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>
                  Part Number
              </th>
              <th>
                  Description
              </th>
              <th>
                  Cost Price
              </th>
              <th>
                  Retail Price
              </th>
              <th>
                  Discount Price
              </th>
              <th>
                  Notes
              </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
       <tbody>
       @foreach($entries as $entry)
           <tr>
              <td>
                 {{$entry->pn}}
              </td>
              <td>
                 {{$entry->desc}}
              </td>
              <td>
                 {{$entry->cp}}
              </td>
              <td>
                 {{$entry->rp}}
              </td>
              <td>

              </td>
              <td>
                 {{$entry->notes}}
              </td>
           </tr>
        @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why would you want add table column programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="discbtn"` to your button not your `div` and change `#` to `.` because you have used `class` and you are targeting it as `id`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".discbtn").click(function () {
    var discValue = $("#disc").val();
    $('#stand td:eq(4)').each(function () {
        if (isNaN($('#stand td:eq(4)').text())) {
            $('#stand td:eq(5)').each(function () {
                $('#stand td:eq(5)').text($('#stand td:eq(4)').text() * discValue);
            })
        }
    })


   })
})
```

Comment: This had no effect

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have tried this and it also gives no output to the column.

Comment: did you check your console ?

Comment: The Console is empty when I input the multiplier. The console in the web browser that is